# Reading an excel sheet and filtering a column using mapreduce program in hadoop

Tags: excel, hadoop, mapreduce

For example, Let me explain it in detail.

Assume initial data will as shown in the following images.

[image]

[image]

This data will be in an excel sheet as shown with n number of rows.  It will typically be a huge amount of data.

I need to filter the column status and output as in different excel sheets or in same workbook.  I want to use a [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) algorithm.

Can anyone please help me with writing the MapReduce code for this problem

Comment: I tried to reformat your question so it is easier to understand; but, it was unclear to me what the content of each table is intended to be used for.  If you could clarify that, I believe it would help you to get and answer.

Comment: Excuse, Actually i tried to insert images but not possible here so that i inserted two links as output images then assume that input sheet contains combination of both the output files. Hope u understood. Please try to open those output links u can see excel sheet images that what exactly need as output